# Google Cloud Liens not protecting from Project Deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have set up gcp liens as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens#listing_liens_on_a_project).

Unfortunately when I try to delete the project using an owner account the project is deleted.
Does it take some time to take effect or is there some other kind of extra configuration?

In order to achieve so I used the commands specified on the documentation

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens create --restrictions=resourcemanager.projects.delete --reason="Super important production system" --project projectId
```

Then I check the rule

```
> gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list --project projectId --format json

[
  {
    "createTime": "2020-01-23T07:53:19.938621Z",
    "name": "liens/p111111111111-420a1a11-8dee-4b07-a7fe-5112b00e898d",
    "origin": "john@doe.com",
    "parent": "projects/111111111111",
    "reason": "Super important production system",
    "restrictions": [
      "resourcemanager.projects.delete"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact command that you used to create the lien?   Can you post the output of gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list

Comment: Hi the original post was updated with the command and the list output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have  the “Project Lien Modifier” role for your user at the Organization level.

Then you can open the cloud shell and run this command

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens create --restrictions=resourcemanager.projects.delete --reason="Important PJ" --project=[YOUR-PJ-NAME] --verbosity=debug
```

** **EDIT:
I test it in a a no-organization project and the lien doesn't work. This feature is in alpha, looks like this does not support individual projects currently. It was made thinking in large organisation with hundreds of projects**

Comment: This is done on an individual account there is no organisation. However I added the role at the owner account. The result is still the same. 
Is lien something that requires organisation?

Comment: I test it in a a no-organization project and the lien doesn't work. This feature is in alpha, looks like this does not support individual projects currently. It was made thinking in large organisation with hundreds of projects.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer with this commend so that I can mark it as the solution for the community.

Comment: i tested in a no organization project and now it works for me.